# What is best practice to develop resizable widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, resizable

Main need : Resizable widget

Minor need : Wide range of Android OS, runs on version 1.6(donut) - 4.04(ics)

On the widget it has images and text onto it. Though the widget is not resizable but there are many custom launchers that allows us to resize the widget. The widget will look awful after resize.

What is the best practices to accomplish this?

Comment: Just a comment, only 0.7% Android users use 1.6 (Donut), and 5.5% use 2.0 and 2.1, so it is better that you make the widget for Android 2.2 and above, this way there will be less feature compatibility issues. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_OS#Market_share)

Comment: Also resizable widgets were introduced into the official android launcher (and apis) in 3.1 see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: If your question is about resizable home screen widget, this link provides no answer to your question.
The app widget guide offers some insight using graphics, but there's no real solution to text resizing automatically, apart from using again 9-patch graphics for all text!
This app is a good example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.apps.reborn.pro